# Floating button over UItableview using storyboards

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have made a table view using prototype cells on tableviewcontroller from storyboards.

I want a floating button over that uitableview. (button won't scroll with the tableview).

While searching for a solution..I found out that it is possible by adding button to the superview (in that case Uiviewcontroller subclasses Uitableview).

Can any one tell me how to do that using storyboards??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best thing you have to do is to create a `UIViewController` and add it a `UITableView`. Then you can add also the `UIButton` you want to the view controller's view. Don't forget to set the view controller to be the delegate and data source for your table view, and to add `<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>` to your view controller interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it using Storyboards and not in code, then you need to use a UIViewController and not a UITableViewController.

Add the UITableView and make it full screen - link up its Delegate and DataSource to the UIViewController and adhere to the two protocols in the .h file of your UIViewController.

When adding the button, drag it into the view hierarchy in the "Document Outline" sidebar, and not by dragging it onto the UITableView. Be careful if you're ever dragging the button around the view because if you drag and drop it on top of the UITableView then it will become a subview of the UITableView. If you want to move it around you'll need to select it and then use the arrow keys.

Anyway, apart from that it should all be very easy - add your constraints to keep it in the right place and you should be able to use the button as normal.